# depmixS4 package how to calculate outputs of HMM on new data

Tags: r, hidden-markov-models

I want to train two hidden Markov models `hmm_up` and `hmm_dw` on two different states `up` and `dw`

```
library(depmixS4)
sliding_window <- function(x,n=5) as.data.frame(embed(x,dimension = n)[,n:1])
# state up
up <- sliding_window(rnorm(200,mean = 0.1))
# state down
dw <- sliding_window(rnorm(200,mean = -0.1))

#   "V5 ~ 1"    I'm not sure if I'm doing it right
hmm_up <- fit(depmix(V5 ~ 1, data = up, nstates = 2,  family = gaussian()))
hmm_dw <- fit(depmix(V5 ~ 1, data = dw, nstates = 2,  family = gaussian()))
```

Next, I would like to get the `log` `likelihood` on the `new_data` from each of the modеls

```
# new up and dw data together
new_data <- sliding_window(c(rnorm(100,mean = 0.1), rnorm(100,mean = -0.1)))
# get log likelihood on new_data from hmm_up and hmm_dw
```

How can I calculate log likelihood, Viterbi etc. on new data?